# Trouble setting active button in HTML/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new to using HTML and CSS and am having a bit of trouble getting buttons to show that they are active (i.e. by default, button1 has alternate colour to show its already selected). When they click on button2, the content above changes (successfully) and then button2 should become the active one.

However, at present, I can't even get button1 to be default active. I have done this successfully elsewhere on the page.

Here is the HTML: *its worth noting I have named my other successful attempt at this class="active" also*

```
<div id="left-top-container">
        <ul id="selectionInfo">                    
            <li id="disc">Noiseproofing Joist Tape</li>
            <li id="compound">Compound</li>
            <li id="clip">Clip</li>
            <li id="sealant">Sealant</li>                    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="left-bottom-container">                
        <ul id="buttons">
            <li id="discSelection" class="active"><a href="#disc">Disc</a></li>
            <li id="compoundSelection"><a href="#compound">Compound</a></li>
            <li id="clipSelection"><a href="#clip">Clip</a></li>
            <li id="sealantSelection"><a href="#sealant">Sealant</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#buttons
{ position:relative; left:-44px; top:-44px; }
#buttons li
{ float:left; list-style:none; }
#buttons li a
{ float:left; list-style:none; position:relative; text-indent:-9999px; }
#discSelection a
{ background: url(/Content/images/unhighlighted.png) no-repeat 0 0; height:88px; width:162px; padding:0; }
#discSelection a:hover, #discSelection a.active
{ background: url(/Content/images/tops.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:162px; height:106px; top:-13px; }
#compoundSelection a
{ background: url(/Content/images/unhighlighted.png) no-repeat -162px 0; height:88px; width:159px; padding:0; }
#compoundSelection a:hover, #compoundSelection a.active 
{ background: url(/Content/images/tops.png) no-repeat -162px 0; width:159px; height:106px; top:-13px; } 
#clipSelection a
{ background: url(/Content/images/unhighlighted.png) no-repeat -321px 0; height:88px; width:159px;  }
#clipSelection a:hover, #clipSelection a.active
{ background: url(/Content/images/tops.png) no-repeat -324px 0; width:159px; height:106px; top:-13px; }
#sealantSelection a
{ background: url(/Content/images/unhighlighted.png) no-repeat -480px 0; height:88px; width:159px; }
#sealantSelection a:hover, #sealantSelection a.active
{ background: url(/Content/images/tops.png) no-repeat -486px 0; width:159px; height:106px; top:-13px; }
```

And here is the JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#main-body-options a").click(function (e) {
    showSlide($(this).parent().index())
    return false;
});
$("#buttons a").click(function (e) {
    showSlide2($(this).parent().index())
    return false;
});
});

function showSlide2(index) {
$("#buttons.active li.active").removeClass("active")
$("#buttons li").eq(index).addClass("active")
$("ul#selectionInfo").animate({ top: -409 * index}, { duration:600, easing:"easeInOutQuint" })
}
```

If I am not clear anywhere please ask or edit to make it more readable.

Comment: with stuff like this you should look into setting up a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net - It makes it far easier for people to provide useful answers.

Comment: put this up on jsfiddle please.

Comment: While waiting for your jsfiddle... I see you've got the following in your html code: `<li id="discSelection" class="active"><a href="#disc">Disc</a></li>` .. And the  the CSS rule `#discSelection a.active` which is incorrect according to your HTML. the `class="active"` should be on your `<a>` tag according to the CSS rule. anyways, waiting for the jsfiddle example...

Comment: @BonyT Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried, but obviously it can't render my images and I can't see anywhere to do that? I will try to set this up on jsfiddle.net and share but thanks for the info guys

Comment: @Ettiene That's probably my problem...

Comment: Then simplify - you could just use colours for backgrounds on the fiddle instead of images - all you need is enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all your css and html and put the active class ONLY on the **a** element

Then modify your jquery to this:

```
$("#buttons a").click(function (e) {
   $("#buttons a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   showSlide2($(this).parent().index())
return false;
});

 function showSlide2(index) {
    $("ul#selectionInfo").animate({ top: -409 * index}, { duration:600, easing:"easeInOutQuint" })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have define the .active class on the **a** element "#sealantSelection **a**.active.

I think if you change that to apply on the **li** element your problem will disappear.

Comment: Even though their picture representations are different for each <li> item?

Comment: yes you can change your selectors to be "#sealantSelection.active a" so when you put the active class on li element, the CSS will apply a new style on the a element